# Aspect breaking bytecode on specific class

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, bytecode

I'm new to AOP, I've created an aspect to trace all methods or classes marked with @Trace annotation. I'm using compile time weaving. (Java 8, Aspectj 1.8, Spring 4)

TraceAspect.java

```
@Aspect
public class TraceAspect {
    private static Map<String, Integer> threadMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Pointcut("@within(Trace) || @annotation(Trace)")
    void annotated(){}
    
    @Around("annotated() && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object trace(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String  threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        String indent = indent(inThread(threadName));

        System.out.println(threadName + " : " + indent + "->  " + joinPoint.getSignature().toString());

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Object ret = joinPoint.proceed();
        long end = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(threadName + " : " + indent + "<-  " + joinPoint.getSignature().toString() + " ended (took " + (end - start) + " nanoseconds)");

        outThread(threadName);
        return ret;
    }

    private String indent(int depth) {
        String result = "";
        for (int index = 0; index < depth; index++) {
            result += "   ";
        }
        return result;
    }

    private int inThread(String threadName) {
        if (threadMap.get(threadName) == null) {
            threadMap.put(threadName, 0);
        }

        int stackDepth = threadMap.get(threadName) + 1;
        threadMap.put(threadName, stackDepth);
        return stackDepth;
    }

    private void outThread(String threadName) {
        int stackDepth = threadMap.get(threadName) - 1;
        threadMap.put(threadName, stackDepth);
    }
}
```

The CryptsyExchange.java (which is a Spring Bean) when marked with @Trace, classloader throws ClassFormat error on build(..) method while initializing that bean in application context...

CryptsyExchange.java

```
@Trace
public class CryptsyExchange {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CryptsyExchange.class);

    private DataService dataService;
    private Configuration config;

    private Converter converter;
    private Exchange exchange;
    private List<CryptsyAccount> accounts = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());
    private CryptsyAccount defaultAccount;

    public static CryptsyExchange build(String name, DataService dataService, ConfigPathBuilder pathBuilder) {
        condition(notNullOrEmpty(name) && notNull(dataService, pathBuilder));

        CryptsyExchange cryptsyExchange = new CryptsyExchange();
        cryptsyExchange.dataService = dataService;


        // Loading configuration
        final Configuration configuration = Configuration.load(pathBuilder.getExchangeConfigPath(name));
        cryptsyExchange.config = configuration;

        // Retrieve corresponding exchange from datastore
        cryptsyExchange.exchange = dataService.registerExchange(cryptsyExchange.config.getString("exchange"));

        // Get accounts from configuration

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> accounts = configuration.getMap("accounts");

        // Initialize accounts
        accounts.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Map<String, String> accountMap = entry.getValue();

            // Retrieve corresponding datastore account
            Account account = dataService.registerAccount(cryptsyExchange.exchange, key);

            // Initialize cryptsy specific account
            CryptsyAccount cryptsyAccount = new CryptsyAccount(account, accountMap.get("key"), accountMap.get("secret"));

            cryptsyExchange.accounts.add(cryptsyAccount);

            if (notNull(accountMap.get("isDefault")) && Boolean.valueOf(accountMap.get("isDefault"))) {
                cryptsyExchange.defaultAccount = cryptsyAccount;
            }
        });

        // Initializing Converter
        cryptsyExchange.converter = cryptsyExchange.new Converter();

        // Recover associations from configuration
        Map<String, String> exchangeCurrencyToCurrency = configuration.getMap("exchangeCurrencyToCurrency");
        Set<String> markedForRemoval = new HashSet<>();

        exchangeCurrencyToCurrency.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            String cryptsyCurrencyCode = entry.getKey();
            String currencySymbol = entry.getValue();

            com.jarvis.data.entity.Currency currency = dataService.getCurrency(currencySymbol);
            if (notNull(currency)) {
                cryptsyExchange.converter.associateCurrency(currency, cryptsyCurrencyCode);
            } else {
                LOGGER.debug("associated currency [" + currencySymbol + "] does not exist in database, removing from configuration");
                markedForRemoval.add(cryptsyCurrencyCode);
            }
        });

        // Removing currency associations missing from database
        if (!markedForRemoval.isEmpty()) {
            markedForRemoval.forEach((currency) -> configuration.remove("exchangeCurrencyToCurrency", currency));
        }

        Map<String, String> exchangeMarketToMarket = configuration.getMap("exchangeMarketToMarket");
        markedForRemoval.clear();

        exchangeMarketToMarket.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            String cryptsyMarketId = entry.getKey();
            String marketName = entry.getValue();

            Market market = dataService.getMarket(marketName);
            if (notNull(market)) {
                cryptsyExchange.converter.associateMarket(market, Integer.valueOf(cryptsyMarketId));
            } else {
                LOGGER.debug("associated market [+" + marketName + "] does not exist, removing from configuration");
                markedForRemoval.add(cryptsyMarketId);
            }
        });

        // Removing market associations missing from database
        if (!markedForRemoval.isEmpty()) {
            markedForRemoval.forEach((market) -> configuration.remove("exchangeMarketToMarket", market));
        }

        // Update configuration
        configuration.save();

        return cryptsyExchange;
    }

    // Lot of other code there
}
```

And of course the stackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 288 in method com.jarvis.exchange.cryptsy.CryptsyExchange.build_aroundBody0(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/jarvis/data/service/DataService;Lcom/jarvis/util/ConfigPathBuilder;Lorg/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint;)Lcom/jarvis/exchange/cryptsy/CryptsyExchange;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:451)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:82)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jarvis.Jarvis.<clinit>(Jarvis.java:10)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
```

I've tried this on any other class on my project (annotation can be applied on Type or method) and it worked, but exactly with this bean build method I'm facing issues and can't find any workaround. Maybe current support for Java 8 by Aspectj is buggy and it actually corrupts bytecode. Or perhaps there is something wrong I've done there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions:

- Do you use full-blown AspectJ or just Spring AOP with @AspectJ syntax?
- Do you compile with source/target level 1.8 or maybe still 1.7?
- Does the exact same code work with Java 7 and AspectJ 1.8.0?
- If not, does it work with Java 7 and AspectJ 1.7.4?
- Can you please provide a stand-alone minimal code sample reproducing the problem? Maybe even on GitHub with a Maven build?) Many of your referenced classes are invisible to me, so I cannot reproducte it.

AJ 1.8.0 is brandnew and some of its problems are actually caused by ECJ (Eclipse Java compiler). Some have already been fixed, so you could try a current [developer build](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php) (select "Last Known Good developer build".

**Update:**

I was able to reproduce the problem with a small code sample, independent of any other classes. The problem is not annotations or simple `forEach` lambdas, but obviously nested `forEach` lambdas.

I filed an AspectJ bug on http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435446.

**Update 2:**

The bug ticket also describes how to work around the problem by excluding lambda calls from the pointcut.

Another workaround I just found is to run the JVM with parameter `-noverify`.

**Update 3:**

The bugfix is done and available as a development build. It will be part of the upcoming AspectJ 1.8.1.

Comment: 1. I use pure AspectJ, spring has nothing to do with my aspects (I intentionally want to keep them separated)

2. I compile both source/target levels to 1.8. 

3,4. Didn't other java versions yet (i need to stick with java 8)

Your're right, there are lot of things going on there that is to much to put there, but seems I found what is the source of the problem. I have an inner class in my CryptsyExchange. I'll update that code so you can see... (yet you wont be able to reproduce unfortunately)

Comment: Yes, i've used -noverify (altough i hope one day plugin will be fixed so that i dont need this flag)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the problem comes from lambda expression usage :(

replacing all lambdas with regular for fixes the problem

```
exchangeCurrencyToCurrency.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
    String cryptsyCurrencyCode = entry.getKey();
    String currencySymbol = entry.getValue();

    com.jarvis.data.entity.Currency currency = dataService.getCurrency(currencySymbol);
    if (notNull(currency)) {
        associateCurrency(currency, cryptsyCurrencyCode);
    } else {
        LOGGER.debug("associated currency [" + currencySymbol + "] does not exist in database, removing from configuration");
        markedForRemoval.add(cryptsyCurrencyCode);
    }
});
```

result

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : exchangeCurrencyToCurrency.entrySet()){
            String cryptsyCurrencyCode = entry.getKey();
            String currencySymbol = entry.getValue();

            com.jarvis.data.entity.Currency currency = dataService.getCurrency(currencySymbol);
            if (notNull(currency)) {
                associateCurrency(currency, cryptsyCurrencyCode);
            } else {
                LOGGER.debug("associated currency [" + currencySymbol + "] does not exist in database, removing from configuration");
                markedForRemoval.add(cryptsyCurrencyCode);
            }
        }
```

Comment: @kriegaex Yet I dont understand why is this happening, maybe Aspectj really is corrupting code?

Comment: the simplest lambda breaks the code with the same error "Arrays.asList("asdf","asdf").forEach((p) -> System.out.println(p));"

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem here, your little lambda from the above comment works nicely with AspectJ 1.8.0 here.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem with a small code sample, independent of any other classes. The problem is not annotations or simple forEach lambdas, but obviously nested forEach lambdas. I filed an AspectJ bug on https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435446

Comment: Yes and I've tested the same code with forEach(anonymous class) approach and it worked fine... I confirm this is nested lambda problem. But there is something i might missing. I'm using Intellij, project is set to use ajc compiler with target bytecode 1.8 version, and i have both java 1.7 and 1.8 installed. As far as i know for ajc will modify source and compile with javac (using JAVA_HOME) am I right?

Comment: I double-checked and also saw the post-compile weaving works if the lambdas have been compiled with *javac*. I have added a corresponding comment to the ticket: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435446#c1. As for your other question: No, ajc does not manipulate the source code, it is meant to be a superset of javac, thus able to understand both plain Java and AspectJ.

Comment: @kriegaex Folowing your link i saw that post compilation weaving solves the issue, could you please explain how can i use PCW instead of CTW? I'm on intellij Idea and apparantly I'm lacking some knowledge in AOP to do this.

Comment: I am totally flabbergasted to see you asking this. I thought that earlier you had written that it had solved your problem, but now I cannot find the text here on the page anymore. I just tried what you told me.

Comment: I have just updated my answer with another workaround (JVM option `-noverify`)

Comment: I'm really sorry for confusion, but it was a mistake, it just delegated compilation, and ignored all aspects thus my code runs. but that didn't solve it :(

Comment: Funny enough, it works. I needed to create two modules in my IntelliJ IDEA project and make one of them dependent on the other. I cannot say for sure because I am away from my PC now. It was a bit trial and error, but in the end it worked.

Comment: I (AspectJ project lead) just fixed up the bug 435446 and at least for the test case that was included it all works now. The size of an invokedynamic instruction was not set correctly which damaged the local variable table. If you want to try it use the latest dev build from http://eclipse.org/aspectj/downloads.php or the 1.8.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from our snapshot maven repo: http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot